# <UnboundField(TextField, ('Study',), {})> where is the problem?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am new to Python, I wanted to create a simple page with Wtforms, but this code gives me UnboundField error.
Can someone help me solve the problem?

Thank you

```py
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms import TextField
from wtforms import SelectField
from wtforms import RadioField
from wtforms import DecimalField
from wtforms import SubmitField

from datetime import datetime
from flask import render_template
from FlaskWebProject1 import app

class StudyManagementForm(Form):
    """This seemingly static class will be transformed
    by the WTForms metaclass constructor"""
    study = TextField("Study")
    active = RadioField("Etude active")
    submit = SubmitField("Ok")

    def __init__(self):
        print ('a')

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/study_management', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def study_management():
    submitForm = StudyManagementForm()

    return render_template(
        'study_management.html',
        form = submitForm
        )
```

And i got UnboundField error :

```
<UnboundField(TextField, ('Study',), {})> 

<UnboundField(RadioField, ('Etude active',), {})>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have class inheritance: `StudyManagementForm(Form)` but you have chosen to specifically overwrite the `__init__()` method by doing this:

```
def __init__(self):
    print('a')
```

This means that the "seemingly static class will NOT be transformed" becuase all that code is now avoided. Instead do:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    print('a')
```

Now the original `Form.__init__()` will be executed and following that, your print statement will be. Unbound fields will be Bound in that process.